# Ender 3 Pro with BLTouch bed leveling stops after 1 test (Marlin 2.0.7.2)

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, bed-leveling

I have an Ender 3 Pro with the BLTouch installed. Firmware is Marlin 2.0.7.2. I followed [this instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsTGH5JvClM&t=590s).

When I start the bed leveling it will go to the center, check it twice and then return to the home position. When I did this with the firmware from Creality it would check 9 different points. I would expect this also from this firmware.

In the Configuration.h I have this setting:

```
#define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 3
```

so I would expect 9 tests.

I double check everyting with the video. The only difference is that the video is based on an older version. The setting

```
#define MIN_PROBE_EDGE = 10
```

is missing in firmware 2.0.7.2.

Is there maybe a new setting that I should enable/disable?

Comment: obviously, something in the frmware is wrong. Without knowing your firmware settings we can't help. Please copy the firmware settings to a pastebin.

Comment: Have you looked into the configuration file and overseen `#define PROBING_MARGIN 10` :-) This is not the problem however!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r2r0yhes